# BroadcastReceiver restart itself after being called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm working alarmManager and since API 19 all alarms are not precise except the ones that were set by using setExact() method. So, if I want to set multiple exact alarms I have use setExact() method many times. I decided that it would be better to set one and then in broadcast receiver set another. The thing is that every BroadcastReceiver is triggered and new alarm is set BroadcastReceiver restart itself.

My code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Date previoudTime = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek-1);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        String sDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyService_alarm.this, MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
        Log.e("Point_1", "Compare1 " + calendar.getTime());
        Log.e("Point_1", "Compare2 " + previoudTime);
        Log.e("Point_1", "Compare " + calendar.getTime().compareTo(previoudTime));
        if(calendar.getTime().compareTo(previoudTime) < 0) {

            int a = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
            calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,a + 1);
            //Log.e("Point_1", "Less " + calendar.getTime());
        }
        Long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        intent1.putExtra("Size_ABC", y);
        intent1.putExtra("Date",sDate);
        intent1.putExtra("Position",position);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService_alarm.this, position, intent1, 0);
        //Also change the time to 24 hours.
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver code:

```
public class MyReceiver_Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
        SQLiteDataBase sqLiteDataBase = new SQLiteDataBase(context);
        final AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sqLiteDataBase.getVolume(intent.getIntExtra("Size_ABC",1)),0);
        final int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //Log.e("Point_1", "Current Volume " + currentVolume);
        //mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.50f,1.0f);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                //Log.e("Point_1", "Volume_after " + audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            }
        }, 5000);
        Log.e("Point_1", "Alarm!!! " + sqLiteDataBase.getVolume(intent.getIntExtra("Size_ABC",1)));
        ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.e("Point_1","Intent_Extra " + intent.getStringExtra("Date"));
        calendar1.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(intent.getStringExtra("Date"), parsePosition));
        int i = calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, i + 3);
        long alarmTime = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        String sDate = dateFormat.format(calendar1.getTime());
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
        intent1.putExtra("Date", sDate);
        intent1.putExtra("Position",intent.getIntExtra("Position",1));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,intent.getIntExtra("Position",1),intent1,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
        Log.e("Point_1","SDateP " + calendar1.getTime());
    }
}
```

Logcat(that is only one part of repeating):

```
Intent_Extra Thu Dec 01 03:15:00 GMT+05:00 2016
12-01 15:15:01.202  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ SDateP Thu Dec 01 03:18:00 GMT+05:00 2016
12-01 15:15:01.252  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ id 21
12-01 15:15:01.262  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Volume 0
12-01 15:15:01.272  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ id 21
12-01 15:15:01.282  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Volume 0
12-01 15:15:01.282  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Alarm!!! 0
12-01 15:15:01.282  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Intent_Extra Thu Dec 01 03:15:00 GMT+05:00 2016
12-01 15:15:01.282  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ SDateP Thu Dec 01 03:18:00 GMT+05:00 2016
12-01 15:15:01.482  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ id 21
12-01 15:15:01.482  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Volume 0
12-01 15:15:01.512  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ id 21
12-01 15:15:01.512  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Volume 0
12-01 15:15:01.512  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Alarm!!! 0
12-01 15:15:01.512  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Intent_Extra Thu Dec 01 03:15:00 GMT+05:00 2016
12-01 15:15:01.512  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ SDateP Thu Dec 01 03:18:00 GMT+05:00 2016
12-01 15:15:01.572  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ id 21
12-01 15:15:01.582  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Volume 0
12-01 15:15:01.602  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ id 21
12-01 15:15:01.602  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Volume 0
12-01 15:15:01.602  20321-20321/com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5 E/Point_1﹕ Alarm!!! 0
```

What is wrong here? How to prevent this repeating?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Your broadcast receiver restart itself...

We can register our receivers in two ways 
1. Static by   Manifest file 
2. Dynamically by  registerReceiver(receiver);

U might hav use both things so nly this happens.
I am a beginner. I jus want to help u. Sorry if I am wrong.
Hope it helps.